# Do asperity junctions break every time a machine starts to rotate?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, friction, material-science, experimental-physics

After reading CONTROL OF MACHINES WITH FRICTION by Brian Armstrong-Helouvry, some questions rised.
The main question I ask you is:
Suppose two metal surfaces in relative motion first in static friction regime, and after a critic displacement (which corresponds to break-away force) in boundary lubrication. What does happen to the asperities junctions in these two regimes? Do they plastically deform and **break**? So if I filtered the oil, would I see these broken asperities caught there?

Comment: Bonded asperities sounds more like a description of galling, Bearing surfaces should have an oil film between them, not metal to metal contact.

Comment: @blacksmith37 Thanks for answering my question! Yeah, I referred to galling when I said ''bonded asperities''. The case I'm studying is particular as the velocity of the gears and other elements of the drive train varies following a sine (of time) function. There is a moment when the velocity is zero or very low. Therefore all regimes of friction are presented in the surfaces in contact. In these conditions of velocity near zero value, total and parcial lubrication don't take place and solid-to-solid contacts do instead.